# No puedo leer en c++ archivos txt creados con c#

Tags: c#, c++, txt

soy relativamente nuevo en esto de programar. Solo manejo lo basico de c++ y el uso de batch. Para ponerlos en mi situacion, quiero hacer un programa que me respalde las carpetas de guardado de varios juegos; ya logre hacerlo en c++ en una aplicacion de consola, pero me parece poco practico y quise intentar hacer una GUI en C#. C# es nuevo para mi, asi que estoy usando ambos, me explico

En C# tengo un boton que me genera varios txt con rutas y un numero de identificacion para cada juego

```
        string text_juego_resp = Convert.ToString(txtjuego.SelectedIndex);
        TextWriter Esc1 = new StreamWriter("Data\\Respaldo\\JuegoResp.txt");
        Esc1.WriteLine(text_juego_resp);

        Esc1.Close();

        string juego_resp = Convert.ToString(rutaresp1.Text);
        TextWriter Esc2 = new StreamWriter("Data\\Respaldo\\RutaResp.txt");
        Esc2.WriteLine(juego_resp);

        Esc2.Close();

        string copiara = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        TextWriter Esc3 = new StreamWriter("Data\\Respaldo\\rutaprogram.txt");
        Esc3.WriteLine(copiara);

        Esc3.Close();
```

Todo bien, de ahi se abre un exe que hice en c++ que lee los txt(que sera el que copiara/borrara las carpetas):

```
int main(){

string texto, re;
ifstream archivo;
ifstream caja;
cout << 22 << endl;
archivo.open("RutaResp.txt",ios::in);

while(!archivo.eof()){
    
    getline(archivo,texto);

}
archivo.close();

caja.open("JuegoResp.txt",ios::in);

cout << 4444<<endl;

while(!caja.eof()){
    
    getline(caja,re);

}
caja.close();

cout << 5555<<endl;

if (texto != "Default"){
    
    const char *c = texto.c_str();
    char a[400];

    sustituir(c, a);
    
}

cout << re << endl;

system ("pause");
return 0;}
```

El problema es al pasar el contenido a las variables string, si los txt son creados con c# los strings quedan vacios y el programa queda en bucle despues de imprimir los 4444(los puse para saber hasta donde corria el codigo); pero si los txt los creo manualmente el problema no ocurre. Se que no deberia estar mezclando ambos lenguajes pero es la forma que tengo por el momento de hacerlo :D

Comment: Es muy normal mezclar lenguajes... ahora mismo estoy escribiendo este comentario en un cuadro de texto habilitado con javascript, en un navegador escrito en una mezcla de c, c++ y python, que corre en un sistema operativo escrito en c. Así que, nada de que apenarse. Sobre tu problema, ¿puedes abrir los archivos con el bloc de notas y todo se ve bien?

Comment: @jachguate Si se ven perfectamente, los edito y aun asi no funcionan en c++

Comment: @Juanjo Gracias por tu comentario, me ayudo mucho, efectivamente es como dices, me esta capturando la siguiente linea, y queda vacio porque el txt generado con c# viene con un salto de linea al final. Lo resolvi quitando el bucle del getline. Me siento tonto por complicarme con esto :u

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo yo mismo :D
El problema era que el txt generado con C# me generaba un salto de linea al final; y al usar el bucle

```
while(!archivo.eof()){

getline(archivo,texto);
}
```

me estaba capturando ese salto de linea y por ende la variable quedaba vacia, asi que solo tuve que deshacerme del !archivo.eof() y especificar la linea mediante un bucle for; problema resuelto :D